# Difference between SUB_DATE() function and directly subtract number from a date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've encountered this MySQL problem on Leetcode. Given table `Temperature`

```
+---------+------------+------------------+
| Id(INT) | Date(DATE) | Temperature(INT) |
+---------+------------+------------------+
|       1 | 2015-01-01 |               10 |
|       2 | 2015-01-02 |               25 |
|       3 | 2015-01-03 |               20 |
|       4 | 2015-01-04 |               30 |
+---------+------------+------------------+
```

The objective is to write a SQL query to find all dates' Ids with higher temperature compared to its previous (yesterday's) dates.

so I wrote some thing as follows, which passed 13/14 test cases:

```
select W1.Id
from Weather as W1, Weather as W2
where W1.Date-1 = W2.Date and W1.Temperature> W2.Temperature
```

I checked a solution on the discussion forum and found a similar solution which passed all cases:

```
select W1.Id
from Weather as W1, Weather as W2
where subdate(W1.Date,1) = W2.Date and W1.Temperature> W2.Temperature
```

so my question would be what is the difference between W1.Date-1 and subdate(W1.Date,1) since subdate is also subtracting 1 day from W1.Date?

Comment: What the type of the field Date? Is it Date or Timestamp?

Comment: give example of your test cases.. Because i checked and get incorrect results for :   SELECT '2015-01-01 10:00:10' -1    OR   SELECT '2015-01-01' -1

Comment: Date subtraction can be written this way: date - interval 1 day. I think you can figure out the difference by yourself

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I tries date - interval 1 day, and it worked.

Comment: Hi@JorgeCampos, it is DATE type I believe

Answer (score 0):

It's the same in mysql.
You can have a test in your mysql database.